# android layout issue for button and textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-xml

I want to create application UI as per image available below. Can anyone here please guide me how can I achieve this?

[image]
[Image Source](http://www.flickr.com/photos/rajeshrathod/6136201696/in/photostream)

Here data like 123 MB, 456MB are dynamic and will keep changing from application itself. So Ideally there should be 2 buttons and inside particular button we will need 2 images to show upload/download  and 2 textview required to display bandwidth count.

But I could not figure that how this could be arrange together?

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: Not a big issue Rajesh..
If you have basic knowledge of Relative and Linear Layouts..then it will do the trick..
If you are new to Android then try clearing your layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple nested `LinearLayouts`. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:text="MOBILE" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_weight="0.25">

        <TextView android:text="123 MB"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow_down" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

        <TextView android:text="456 MB"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow_up" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:text="WIFI" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_weight="0.25">

        <TextView android:text="123 MB"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow_down" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

        <TextView android:text="456 MB"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/arrow_up" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:** Any of the `LinearLayout` can be set to `clickable` and with `onClickListener` you can register any action to it.